# Golang: Stack multiple method calls on one line

Tags: function, methods, go

Getting started with Go.
I'm trying to write a function that title cases a first name then caps the second.
Why can't I stack method calls as below?

(The reason why I want to put a .ToLower before is because the .Title only caps the first letter leaving the rest unchanged)

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"
)

func main() {
  firstName := "mElVIn"
  lastName := "themelvINATor"
  fmt.Println(nameCap(firstName, lastName))
}

func nameCap(s1, s2 string) (str1, str2 string) {
  s1 = strings.ToLower(s1).Title(s1)
  s2 = strings.ToUpper(s2)

  return s1, s2
}
```

Comment: Because Title is a function inside of the strings package, and isn't available on strings natively. You're trying to do <somestring>.Title(), which isn't available. You would need to do strings.<somestring>.Title().

Comment: But when i write only s1 = strings.Title(s1) it caps's the first letter?

Comment: What is the output you're expecting? Is it "Melvin THEMELVINATOR"?

Comment: I have provided you a couple of solutions as answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to do something like this (modify for your use case, I'm not entirely sure the output you're trying to get):

```
type myString string

func main() {
    firstName := "mElVIn"
    lastName := "themelvINATor"
    fmt.Println(nameCap(firstName, lastName))
}

func (s myString) Title(ss string) string {
    return strings.Title(ss)
}

func nameCap(s1, s2 string) (str1, str2 string) {
    s1 = myString(strings.ToLower(s1)).Title(s1)
    s2 = strings.ToUpper(s2)

    return s1, s2
}
```

FWIW, there's nothing wrong with doing it without chaining:

```
func nameCap(s1, s2 string) (str1, str2 string) {
    s1 = strings.ToLower(s1)
    s1 = strings.Title(s1)
    s2 = strings.ToUpper(s2)

    return s1, s2
}
```

GoPlay: http://play.golang.org/p/BcJTuBRqbx

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I think i'll stick with just doing it twice without chaining as I'm new to Go. Thanks again!